# Extra Blob Created after Sink in Data Flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm importing from Snowflake to Azure blob using data flow activity in Azure Data Factory.
I noticed that whenever I created a blob thru sink (placed inside provider/Inbound/ folder), I get an extra empty blob file outside Inbound.

Does this happen for all data flow sink to blob?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's very common and not unique to Data Factory. They are remnants of data movement/staging/leasing operations and can be safely deleted or ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I had created a data flow and loaded data to blob from snowflake and I don't see any additional blob file generated outside my sink folder.

Make sure the sink connection is pointed to the correct folder and also double-check if any other process is running other than this dataflow which is causing to create an extra file outside the sink folder.

**Snowflake source**:

[image]

**Sink**:

[image]

**Output file path** to generate the out file:

[image]

**Sink setting** to add a date as the filename:

[image]

[image]

**Output folder**:

[image]

**Output file** generated after executing the data flow.

[image]